# Archivo jar no se ejecuta si no está en su ubicación original

Tags: java, jframe, jar

Mi problema es el siguiente:
Cree un jar mediante netBeans de manera automática, con el botón que compila y crea el ejecutable al mismo tiempo. Dicho jar se ejecuta de manera normal siempre y cuando éste esté en su dirección original; al momento de mover el jar a cualquier otra parte del mismo ordenador, éste no se muestra en lo absoluto.
Mi pregunta es la siguiente: ¿Cómo puedo solucionar este problema para que sea portable al 100%?
[image: El jar se ejecuta de manera normal siempre y cuando esté en la ubicación original, que es la que muestro en la captura.]

[image: Muestra de la correcta ejecución del programa.]

[image: Sin embargo, al cambiar el ejecutable a otra dirección(dentro de la misma computadora), éste no se ejecuta.]

[image: Muestra la NO ejecución del programa.]

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera ademas de agregar el código del programa para ver como puedes hacerlo portable. Saludos.

Comment: Proporciona el código de tu aplicación para analizarlo, también y muy importante, corre el JAR al que cambiaste de ubicación desde el CMD de Windows y allí verás reflejado por qué razón(es) no arranca.

Comment: @Johnny Ésto es lo que muestra al momento de ejecutarlo mediante cmd. [http://prntscr.com/jm8w4w]

Answer (score 0):

public class Auxilio extends javax.swing.JFrame {

```
boolean ban = true, flag = true, flag2 = true, bP = true;
int puntos = 0, cont = 0, hora = 0, minutos = 0, segundos = 0, tiempoSeg = 0;
String path;
JTextArea area;

public Auxilio() {

    initComponents();
    hilo.start();
    setResizable(false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setTitle("Simulación Auxilio - 4° Semestre M-11");
    /**
     * Validación para permitir únicamente letras y espacios en el el área
     * de texto.
     */
    nombreA.addKeyListener(
            new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            if (!Character.isAlphabetic(e.getKeyChar()) && !Character.isSpaceChar(e.getKeyChar())) {
                e.consume();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Hilo que se toma en cuenta el tiempo ocupado por el usuario para
 * contestar el examen.
 */
Thread hilo = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        AudioStream audio = null;
        try {
            hora = 0;
            minutos = 0;
            segundos = 0;
            int num = (int) (Math.random() * 20) + 40;
            int t1 = num / 6, t2 = num / 6, t3 = num / 6, t4 = num / 6, t5 = num / 6, t6 = num / 6;
            while (flag) {
                try {
                    segundos++;
                    tiempoSeg++;
                    if (segundos > 59) {
                        segundos = 0;
                        minutos++;
                    }
                    if (minutos > 59) {
                        segundos = 0;
                        minutos = 0;
                        hora++;
                    }
                    /**
                     * Sección del hilo en donde se evalúa la imagen que
                     * deberá mostrarse con base al tiempo que ha
                     * transcurrido en el examen.
                     */
                    if (tiempoSeg < t1) {
                        path = "1.png";
                        URL url = this.getClass().getResource(path);
                        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
                        p3.setIcon(icon);
                    }
                    if (tiempoSeg > t1 && tiempoSeg < (t1 + t2)) {
                        path = "2.png";
                        URL url = this.getClass().getResource(path);
                        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
                        p3.setIcon(icon);
                    }
                    if (tiempoSeg > (t1 + t2) && tiempoSeg < (t1 + t2 + t3)) {
                        path = "3.png";
                        URL url = this.getClass().getResource(path);
                        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
                        p3.setIcon(icon);
                    }
                    if (tiempoSeg > (t1 + t2 + t3) && tiempoSeg < (t4 * 4)) {
                        path = "4.png";
                        URL url = this.getClass().getResource(path);
                        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
                        p3.setIcon(icon);
                    }
                    if (tiempoSeg > (num)) {
                        path = "5.png";
                        URL url = this.getClass().getResource(path);
                        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
                        p3.setIcon(icon);
                    }
                    if (path.equals("5.png") && tiempoSeg < (num + 10)) {
                        String sonido = "C:\\Users\\GamalielJakousi\\Documents\\Universidad\\Simulación\\src\\src\\bip.wav";
                        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sonido);
                        audio = new AudioStream(in);
                        AudioPlayer.player.start(audio);
                    }

                    if (tiempoSeg >= (num + 10)) {
                        path = "6.png";
                        URL url = this.getClass().getResource(path);
                        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
                        p3.setIcon(icon);
                    }
                    if (path.equals("5.png") && flag2) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡ATENCIÓN!\n ¡La persona está a punto de morir!");
                        flag2 = false;
                    }
                    if (path.equals("6.png")) {
                        segundos = 0;
                        minutos = 0;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡ESTAMOS DE LUTO!\nLa persona ha muerto.");
                        flag = false;
                    }
                    if (puntos >= 80 && bP) {
                        path = "1.png";
                        URL url = this.getClass().getResource(path);
                        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
                        p3.setIcon(icon);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "¡FELICIDADES!\n ¡Sálvaste al paciente!");
                        bP = false;
                    }
                    tiempo.setText(hora + ":" + minutos + ":" + segundos);
                    Thread.sleep(999);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Auxilio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                audio.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Auxilio.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
};

/**
 * Cambia el ícono de la ventana por el indicado.
 *
 * @return el ícono nuevo de la ventana.
 */
@Override
public Image getIconImage() {
    Image retValue = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().
            getImage(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("src/Primeros-auxilios.png"));

    return retValue;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    buttonGroup1 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
    jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
    buttonGroup2 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
    jRadioButton6 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    jRadioButton7 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    jRadioButton8 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    jRadioButton9 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    jRadioButton10 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    p2A1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    buttonGroup3 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
    buttonGroup4 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
    buttonGroup5 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    hombreS = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    mujerS = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    p1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    edadList = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
    jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    nuevaEncuesta = new javax.swing.JButton();
    tiempo = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    p2F = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    p2E = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    p2D = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    p2C = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    p2B = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    p2A = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    p1A = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    p1B = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    p1C = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    p1D = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    p1E = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    p3F = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    p3E = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    p3D = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    p3C = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    p3B = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    p3A = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    jLabel11 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel12 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    p3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    p4F = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    p4E = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    p4D = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    p4C = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    p4B = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    p4A = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    jLabel13 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel14 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    p5F = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    p5E = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    p5D = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    p5C = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    p5B = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    p5A = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    finalizar1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel15 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    nombreA = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    jMenu1.setText("jMenu1");

    buttonGroup2.add(jRadioButton6);
    jRadioButton6.setText("Obstrucción por un objeto");

    buttonGroup2.add(jRadioButton7);
    jRadioButton7.setText("Exceso de alcohol");

    buttonGroup2.add(jRadioButton8);
    jRadioButton8.setText("Problemas de esofágo");

    buttonGroup2.add(jRadioButton9);
    jRadioButton9.setText("Lesión en la cabeza");

    buttonGroup2.add(jRadioButton10);
    jRadioButton10.setText("Asma");

    buttonGroup2.add(p2A1);
    p2A1.setText("Comer demasiado");

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setIconImage(getIconImage());
    getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

    jPanel1.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());
    getContentPane().add(jPanel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(224, 120, -1, -1));

    buttonGroup1.add(hombreS);
    hombreS.setText("Hombre");
    getContentPane().add(hombreS, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 180, -1, 20));

    buttonGroup1.add(mujerS);
    mujerS.setText("Mujer");
    getContentPane().add(mujerS, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 200, -1, -1));

    p1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 204));
    p1.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

    edadList.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "--", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23" }));
    p1.add(edadList, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(59, 127, -1, -1));

    jLabel4.setText("Nombre y apellido");
    p1.add(jLabel4, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(23, 102, -1, -1));

    jLabel2.setText("Sexo");
    p1.add(jLabel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 158, -1, 20));

    jLabel3.setText("Edad");
    p1.add(jLabel3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(25, 130, -1, -1));

    nuevaEncuesta.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    nuevaEncuesta.setText("NUEVA ENCUESTA");
    nuevaEncuesta.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            nuevaEncuestaActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    p1.add(nuevaEncuesta, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(387, 570, 210, 38));

    tiempo.setEditable(false);
    tiempo.setText("0:00:00");
    p1.add(tiempo, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(230, 567, 50, -1));

    jLabel8.setText("TIEMPO: ");
    p1.add(jLabel8, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(180, 570, -1, -1));

    buttonGroup2.add(p2F);
    p2F.setText("Obstrucción por un objeto");
    p1.add(p2F, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(630, 330, -1, -1));

    buttonGroup2.add(p2E);
    p2E.setText("Exceso de alcohol");
    p1.add(p2E, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(490, 330, -1, -1));

    buttonGroup2.add(p2D);
    p2D.setText("Problemas de esofágo");
    p1.add(p2D, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(340, 330, -1, -1));

    buttonGroup2.add(p2C);
    p2C.setText("Lesión en la cabeza");
    p1.add(p2C, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(210, 330, -1, -1));

    buttonGroup2.add(p2B);
    p2B.setText("Asma");
    p1.add(p2B, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(140, 330, -1, -1));

    buttonGroup2.add(p2A);
    p2A.setText("Comer demasiado");
    p1.add(p2A, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 330, -1, -1));

    p1A.setText("Pedir ayuda");
    p1.add(p1A, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 250, -1, -1));

    p1B.setText("Darle un golpe en la espalda");
    p1.add(p1B, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(100, 250, -1, -1));

    jLabel7.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
    jLabel7.setText("INSTRUCCIONES: IDENTIFICA EL CASO DE ASFIXIA");
    p1.add(jLabel7, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 280, -1, -1));

    jLabel5.setText("¿Qué puede funcionar para ayudar a una persona que se está ahogando?");
    p1.add(jLabel5, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 230, -1, -1));

    p1C.setText("Darle agua");
    p1.add(p1C, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(290, 250, -1, -1));

    p1D.setText("Usar una silla");
    p1.add(p1D, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(380, 250, -1, -1));

    p1E.setText("Dejarlo morir");
    p1.add(p1E, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(480, 250, -1, -1));

    jLabel9.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/src/logo-auxilio2.png"))); // NOI18N
    p1.add(jLabel9, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(270, 10, -1, -1));

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("SIMULACIÓN");
    p1.add(jLabel1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 20, -1, -1));

    jLabel10.setText("Hombre se encuentra platicando con sus amigos y comienza a tocer");
    p1.add(jLabel10, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 310, -1, -1));

    buttonGroup3.add(p3F);
    p3F.setText("Obstrucción por un objeto");
    p1.add(p3F, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(630, 380, -1, -1));

    buttonGroup3.add(p3E);
    p3E.setText("Exceso de alcohol");
    p1.add(p3E, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(490, 380, -1, -1));

    buttonGroup3.add(p3D);
    p3D.setText("Problemas de esofágo");
    p1.add(p3D, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(340, 380, -1, -1));

    buttonGroup3.add(p3C);
    p3C.setText("Lesión en la cabeza");
    p1.add(p3C, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(210, 380, -1, -1));

    buttonGroup3.add(p3B);
    p3B.setText("Asma");
    p1.add(p3B, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(140, 380, -1, -1));

    buttonGroup3.add(p3A);
    p3A.setText("Comer demasiado");
    p1.add(p3A, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 380, -1, -1));

    jLabel11.setText("Señor se encuentra en un banquete familiar");
    p1.add(jLabel11, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 360, -1, -1));

    jLabel12.setText("Sujeto comienza a realizar forzadas inhalaciones");
    p1.add(jLabel12, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 410, -1, -1));
    p1.add(p3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 550, -1, -1));

    buttonGroup4.add(p4F);
    p4F.setText("Obstrucción por un objeto");
    p1.add(p4F, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(630, 430, -1, -1));

    buttonGroup4.add(p4E);
    p4E.setText("Exceso de alcohol");
    p1.add(p4E, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(490, 430, -1, -1));

    buttonGroup4.add(p4D);
    p4D.setText("Problemas de esofágo");
    p1.add(p4D, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(340, 430, -1, -1));

    buttonGroup4.add(p4C);
    p4C.setText("Lesión en la cabeza");
    p1.add(p4C, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(210, 430, -1, -1));

    buttonGroup4.add(p4B);
    p4B.setText("Asma");
    p1.add(p4B, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(140, 430, -1, -1));

    buttonGroup4.add(p4A);
    p4A.setText("Comer demasiado");
    p1.add(p4A, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 430, -1, -1));

    jLabel13.setText("Seleccione todas aquellas que considere correctas.");
    p1.add(jLabel13, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(450, 230, -1, -1));

    jLabel14.setText("Muchacho se encuentra en depresión debido a que su novia terminó con él el día anterior");
    p1.add(jLabel14, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 460, -1, -1));

    buttonGroup5.add(p5F);
    p5F.setText("Obstrucción por un objeto");
    p1.add(p5F, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(630, 480, -1, -1));

    buttonGroup5.add(p5E);
    p5E.setText("Exceso de alcohol");
    p1.add(p5E, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(490, 480, -1, -1));

    buttonGroup5.add(p5D);
    p5D.setText("Problemas de esofágo");
    p1.add(p5D, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(340, 480, -1, -1));

    buttonGroup5.add(p5C);
    p5C.setText("Lesión en la cabeza");
    p1.add(p5C, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(210, 480, -1, -1));

    buttonGroup5.add(p5B);
    p5B.setText("Asma");
    p1.add(p5B, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(140, 480, -1, -1));

    buttonGroup5.add(p5A);
    p5A.setText("Comer demasiado");
    p1.add(p5A, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(10, 480, -1, -1));

    finalizar1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    finalizar1.setText("FINALIZAR");
    finalizar1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            finalizar1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    p1.add(finalizar1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(610, 570, 167, 38));

    jLabel6.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/src/primeros-auxilios-cruz-roja-02-535x535.png"))); // NOI18N
    jLabel6.setEnabled(false);
    p1.add(jLabel6, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(330, 0, 500, 540));

    jLabel15.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
    jLabel15.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 255));
    jLabel15.setText("ESTADO DEL PACIENTE");
    p1.add(jLabel15, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(20, 520, -1, -1));
    p1.add(nombreA, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(130, 97, 270, -1));

    getContentPane().add(p1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 830, 630));

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void nuevaEncuestaActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    path = "1.png";
    URL url = this.getClass().getResource(path);
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
    p3.setIcon(icon);
    repaint();
    ban = true;
    flag = true;
    flag2 = true;
    bP = true;
    hora = 0;
    minutos = 0;
    segundos = 0;
    tiempoSeg = 0;
    p1A.setSelected(false);
    p1B.setSelected(false);
    p1C.setSelected(false);
    p1D.setSelected(false);
    p1E.setSelected(false);
    edadList.setSelectedIndex(0);
    nombreA.setText("");
    buttonGroup1.clearSelection();
    buttonGroup2.clearSelection();
    buttonGroup3.clearSelection();
    buttonGroup4.clearSelection();
    buttonGroup5.clearSelection();
    puntos = 0;
}                                             

private void finalizar1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    ban = false;
    flag2 = false;
    String nombre = nombreA.getText();
    if (!nombre.equals("")) {
        String edad = edadList.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String sexo = "";
        if (hombreS.isSelected()) {
            sexo = "Hombre";
        } else if (mujerS.isSelected()) {
            sexo = "Mujer";
        }
        if (!edad.equals("") && !edad.equals("--")) {
            if (!sexo.equals("")) {
                /**
                 * Evaluación de las respuestas.
                 *
                 * Pregunta 1.
                 */
                if (p1A.isSelected()) {
                    puntos += 10;
                }
                if (p1B.isSelected()) {
                    puntos += 0;
                }
                if (p1C.isSelected()) {
                    puntos += 5;
                }
                if (p1D.isSelected()) {
                    puntos += 5;
                }
                if (p1E.isSelected()) {
                    puntos -= 100;
                }
                /**
                 * Pregunta 2.
                 */
                if (p2A.isSelected()) {
                    puntos += 10;
                }
                if (p2B.isSelected()) {
                    puntos += 5;
                }
                if (p2C.isSelected()) {
                    puntos += 0;
                }
                if (p2D.isSelected()) {
                    puntos += 5;
                }
                if (p2E.isSelected()) {
                    puntos += 0;
                }
                if (p2F.isSelected()) {
                    puntos += 20;
                }
                /**
                 * Pregunta 3.
                 */
                if (p3A.isSelected()) {
                    puntos += 20;
                }
                if (p3B.isSelected()) {
                    puntos += 0;
                }
                if (p3C.isSelected()) {
                    puntos += 0;
                }
                if (p3D.isSelected()) {
                    puntos += 0;
                }
                if (p3E.isSelected()) {
                    puntos += 0;
                }
                if (p3F.isSelected()) {
                    puntos += 10;
                }
                /**
                 * Pregunta 4.
                 */
                if (p4A.isSelected()) {
                    puntos += 0;
                }
                if (p4B.isSelected()) {
                    puntos += 20;
                }
                if (p4C.isSelected()) {
                    puntos += 0;
                }
                if (p4D.isSelected()) {
                    puntos += 0;
                }
                if (p4E.isSelected()) {
                    puntos += 0;
                }
                if (p4F.isSelected()) {
                    puntos += 0;
                }
                /**
                 * Pregunta 5.
                 */
                if (p5A.isSelected()) {
                    puntos += 0;
                }
                if (p5B.isSelected()) {
                    puntos += 10;
                }
                if (p5C.isSelected()) {
                    puntos += 5;
                }
                if (p5D.isSelected()) {
                    puntos += 0;
                }
                if (p5E.isSelected()) {
                    puntos += 20;
                }
                if (p5F.isSelected()) {
                    puntos += 0;
                }
                String mensaje = String.format("%-50s %20s %30s %40s %41s\n", "NOMBRE", "EDAD", "SEXO", "PUNTAJE", "TIEMPO");
                String resultado1 = String.format("%-50s", nombre);
                String resultado2 = String.format("%20s", edad);
                String resultado3 = String.format("%30s", sexo);
                String resultado4 = String.format("%40s", puntos + "/100");
                String resultado5 = String.format("%45s", hora + " horas " + minutos + " minutos " + segundos + " segundos ");
                String resultados = mensaje + resultado1 + resultado2 + resultado3 + resultado4 + resultado5;
                area = new JTextArea(resultados);
                area.setEditable(false);
                area.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.BOLD, 10));
                if (cont == 0) {
                    cont++;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, area);
                    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "-- Resultados --\nNombre: " + nombre + "\nEdad: " + edad + "\nSexo: " + sexo + "\nPUNTUACIÓN: " + puntos + "/100" + "\nTiempo: " + hora + " horas " + minutos + " minutos " + segundos + " segundos ");
                } else {
                    int ran = (int) (Math.random() * 30) + 1;
                    String mejora = String.format("%-30s", "MEJORA: " + ran + "%");
                    resultados = mensaje + resultado1 + resultado2 + resultado3 + resultado4 + resultado5 + "\n\n\n\n\n" + mejora;
                    area = new JTextArea(resultados);
                    area.setEditable(false);
                    area.setFont(new Font(Font.DIALOG, Font.BOLD, 10));
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, area);
                    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "-- Resultados --\nNombre: " + nombre + "\nEdad: " + edad + "\nSexo: " + sexo + "\nPUNTUACIÓN: " + puntos + "/100" + "\nTiempo: " + hora + " horas " + minutos + " minutos " + segundos + " segundos " + "\nMejora: " + ran + "%");
                }

            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe seleccionar su sexo para finalizar.");
            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe seleccionar su edad para continuar.");
        }
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debe llenar todos los campos para poder finalizar");
    }
    puntos = 0;
}                                          

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Auxilio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Auxilio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Auxilio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Auxilio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Auxilio().setVisible(true);

        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

La App lanza un `NoClassDeffoundError`, no sabe donde está la clase `AbsoluteLayout`, la cual pertenece a un paquete `org.netbeans.lib.awtextra`. Hasta donde sé [netbeans-absolutelayout](/questions/tagged/netbeans-absolutelayout) no viene por defecto en la JDK como parte de swing sino que es una librería aparte, exclusiva de tu IDE Netbeans, allí radica la razón por la cual corre en los directorios hechos por ese entorno de desarrollo y no fuera de ellos.

La solución es que importes y/o agregues la librería del `AbsoluteLayout` (el cual estoy seguro también es un JAR) al classpath del JAR que deseas distribuir.

> Project Properties > Libraries > Compile (tab) > Add JAR/Folder

Comment: Intenté el hacerlo, pero al momento de me di cuenta que el proyecto en el cuál estoy realizando el jar ya cuenta con dicha librería.
De cualquier forma descargué una por medio de Internet y se la agregué, sin embargo sigue presentando el mismo problema.
Screen: http://prntscr.com/jmp0o8